# K-18 tickets in Finland

Tags: tickets, finland, events

What is the difference between K-18 ticket and regular ticket for an event (concert)?. It has probably something to do with adult/not adult distinction.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, remember to accept it (using the green check mark on the left).

Answer (score 11):

K-18 tickets are for people 18+ and it means that they're selling alcohol, usually. If you have a non-K 18 ticket, you don't get access to the seperate bar area.

Comment: +1, this is correct. *If* there are separate K18 tickets (= for adults) and non-K18 tickets (often marked "S" as in *sallittu*) for a concert, that would in my experience always be related to access to a bar area (*anniskelualue* in Finnish).

Comment: Note that it may not actually matter which ticket you buy; if you're over 18 you can go to the bar area, otherwise you can't. At least [that's how it is in Nosturi](http://www.elmu.fi/node/271), one of the rare venues I know in Helsinki that have gigs allowing minors but still selling alcohol.